# Not showing correct data even though the id is passed

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have three ways of showing Galleries( all galleries, author galleries and active user galleries). The last one is not working.

Layout page.

```
function Layout() {
    const activeUser = useSelector(userSelector);
    const isUserAuthenticated = useSelector(isAuthenticated);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        if(isAuthenticated){
            dispatch(getActiveUser())
        }
    },[]) 
    
<Route exact path="/galleries">
    <GalleriesApp />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/authors/:id">
    <GalleriesApp />
</Route>
<Route exact path="/my-galleries">
    <GalleriesApp my_id={isUserAuthenticated ? activeUser.id : null}/>
</Route>
```

For the my-galleries path I send the active user id as props and it gets sent through when the user clicks on the link but I it shows identical page as the main GalleriesApp.

GalleriesApp page.

```
function GalleriesApp({my_id = null}) {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const galleries = useSelector(selectGalleries);
  const term = useSelector(selectSearchTerm);
  const user_id = useSelector(selectSearchUserId);
  const { id } = useParams(); 

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getActiveUser(id))
  },[id])

  console.log(my_id);
  console.log(id);
 
   useEffect(() => {
      if(my_id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: my_id, term: null}));
      } 
      if(id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: id, term: null}));
      }
      else{
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(null));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: null, term: null}));
      }
  }, [my_id, id, dispatch]);

  function handlePaginate(page) {
      if(my_id){
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: page, user_id: my_id, term: term}));
      } 
      if(id){
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: page, user_id: id, term: term}));
      }else{
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: page, user_id: null, term: term}));
      }        
  }

  function handleSearchTerm(e) {
      dispatch(setSearchTerm(e.target.value));
  }

  function handleSearch() {
      dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: user_id, term: term}))
  }

  return (
  <div>
      <div>
        <h1>{my_id && 'My '}{id && galleries.data.length ? (`${galleries?.data[0]?.user?.first_name}'s `) 
          : (<></>)}
          Galleries </h1>
          
          {galleries.data.length ? (
              <div>
                  <GallerySearch 
                      handleSearchTerm={handleSearchTerm}
                      handleSearch={handleSearch}
                  />
                  <ul>
                      {galleries.data.map((gallery) =>(
                          <GalleryRow key={gallery.id} gallery={gallery}/>
                      ))}
                  </ul>
                  {galleries.current_page !== galleries.last_page && (
                      <button onClick={() => handlePaginate(galleries.current_page + 1)}>
                          Load More
                      </button>
                  )}
              </div>
          ) : (
              <div>There are no galleries</div>
          )}
      </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

I expected to get the active user galleries when going to my-galleries. Even though the id is passed successfully through props I get the exact same GalleriesApp page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect()` has a logic issue.  This code:

```js
      if(my_id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: my_id, term: null}));
      } 
      if(id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: id, term: null}));
      }
      else{
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(null));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: null, term: null}));
      }
```

will hit the `else` case in BOTH the `/galleries` and the `/my-galleries` cases.  For `/my-galleries`, it will first run over the `if (my_id)` block but then will ALSO run over the `else` block, thus negating the work done in the `if (my_id)` block.

I think your situation will be fixed if you change the code to:

```js
      if(my_id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: my_id, term: null}));
      } 
      else if(id){
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(id));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: id, term: null}));
      }
      else{
          dispatch(setSearchUserId(null));
          dispatch(getGalleries({ page: 1, user_id: null, term: null}));
      }
```

(see the `else if` !!)